# Creating MBO files with MapBasic and Notepad++

Tags: mapinfo, mapbasic

[Note: I have been using Notepad++ (with some customisations as per [this page](http://www.twiav.nl/php/mapbasic.php)), rather than MapBasic itself. This may make things a bit trickier, but so far the time saved in development has been worth the extra hassle during setup.]

I am trying to start using project files with MapBasic. As I understand it the process is as follows: compile your modules from .mb files into .mbo files. Then process the .mbp file which links the .mbo files together and, if there are no errors, creates a .mbx.

This makes sense to me except for one thing...how do i get my .mb files to compile to .mbo instead of .mbx? What am I missing?!

Comment: It really is well worth setting up Notepad++ for Mapbasic development. +1 for including the link to the instructions.

Comment: Yep, definitely worth doing. For the record I've been trying to set up projects using the default MapBasic editor as well, just to check it's not my Notepad++ config that's causing the problems. So far there's no difference in the outcomes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the .mb files have a Main sub in them, they will compile to .mbx.

Remove the main and they will compile to an .mbo file

Comment: Hmmm, doesn't appear to make a difference. All I have in the .mb is 'note "test"' and it still compiles to a .mbx. Also, I've been using CoordinateExtractor.mb as an example and that uses a Sub Main and is linked as a .mbo.

Comment: I have found that sometimes its best to compile each of my mb files separately. One of your mb files should still have a main sub in it. I just put the following into an .mb file and it compiled to an mbo. 
Declare sub other

Sub Other

 Note "test"

End Sub

Comment: Yes, I've been compiling each .mb individually so I can check for errors at each stage. Which is lucky as the most basic test failed! You're right, your code does create a .mbo. But mine (Note "test") creates an .mbx. I guess if you only have commands and no sub definitions then it counts the entire file as one big Sub Main? It makes sense, now that I think about it. Thanks!

Comment: Hang on a minute though... If one of my files should have a Sub Main in it, how do I make that one a .mbo? Can you link one .mbx with some .mbos?

Comment: Hmmm. CoordinateExtractor.mb that comes in the mapbasic examples includes a Sub Main and compiles as a .mbo, so it is possible...

Comment: Its to do with .def files. If you have a .def file defining all of your subs, none of the declarations are within the individual .mb files. You then include the .def file in each .mb file using a 'Include "filename.def"' statement. You can then have 1 main sub in one of your .mb files, which is where the program starts.

Comment: CoordinateExtractor.mb has the line "declare sub main". The .def files that are included do not include this line and are mainly just constant definitions.

Comment: From MapBasic Help "Whenever you choose Project > Compile Current File, MapBasic tries to compile the current
file into an executable application file (ending with .mbx). However, if the program file contains
calls to functions or procedures that are not in the file, MapBasic cannot create an .mbx file. In
this case, MapBasic assumes that the program is part of a larger project. MapBasic then builds
an object file (.mbo) instead of an executable file (.mbx). MapBasic also creates an object file
whenever the module that you are compiling does not have a Main procedure."

Comment: Aha! That explains it. I must have missed that bit. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Just posting this to make the answer easier to find. MapBasic will build an object file(.mbo) whenever:

- the MAIN procedure is missing from the module that you are compiling. (Please note: an application can only have one MAIN procedure, so only on object mile can hold this procedure; all others won't.)
- the module contains calls to functions and procedures that are not in the file. Calling a function or sub procedure located in another module is known as an external reference.